# Using spring integration as a mediator

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I try to use Spring integration as a simple mediator. We have a webapp residing on the intranet which can not be accessed from the outside. Now I want to expose this app through a mediator in the DMZ. This simply means that all url:s like http://gateway/TheApp/* should be forwarded to http://internal/TheApp/*. Really simple in theory but it seems that the component for handling outgoing http-reuests in Spring integration (HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler) needs an explicut URI, i.e no wildcard matching. Can this be achieved with Spring integration?

Answer (score 1):

The inbound gateway puts the url into a header; you can simply use an expression on the outbound gateway...

```
url-expression="headers['http_requestUrl'].replace('gateway', 'internal')"
```

If you are using Java `@Configuration`, you can use the constructor that takes an `Expression`...

```
Expression expression = new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression(
    "headers['http_requestUrl'].replace('gateway', 'internal')");
```

[This test case](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-http/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/http/HttpProxyScenarioTests-context.xml) does something similar by grabbing just the query string and appends it to a new URL.

In that case, it puts the query string in the payload; it could easily by added as a header instead (e.g. for a POST), using the `<int:header/>` child element.